# Binding combobox to dictionary, dropdown list displays keys and values

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been racking my brain on this, but can't seem to come to solution so..
I have a combobox that displays a list of languages tied to a dictionary in the viewmodel with a list of languages and a language key enumeration. The dictionary displays the language string in whatever language is being displayed, the key is used to set that language, everything works fine, except.. though the selected item displays the proper language string, the dropdown list shows the key, value pair like:
[English, Anglais]
[French, Francais]
etc.
Here is how I have the combo set up:

```
<ComboBox Name="LanguageCombo"
        DisplayMemberPath="Value"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageDictionary}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Language, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectedValuePath="Key">
</ComboBox>
```

And in the viewmodel:

```
private Dictionary<Languages, string> _languageDictionary = LanguageManager.LanguageDictionary;

public Dictionary<Languages, string> LanguageDictionary
{
    get { return _languageDictionary; }
    set
    {
        if (_languageDictionary != value)
        {
            _languageDictionary = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LanguageDictionary");
        }
    }
}

public string Language
{
    get { return LanguageManager.Language.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (LanguageManager.Language != value)
            {
                // do some stuff
                RaisePropertyChanged("Language");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, here's some more code, so far it is a property inside a class called 'LanguageManager, which does the lifting, and a static class with dictionaries called 'LanguageNames'..

LanguageManager:

```
public static Dictionary<Languages, string> LanguageDictionary
        {
            get { return LanguageNames.CulturedNames[LanguageNames.Culture]; }
        }
```

LanguageNames:

> ```
> public static class LanguageNames
> {
>     public static CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }
>     public static readonly Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<Languages, string>> CulturedNames;
>
>     static LanguageNames()
>     {
>        CulturedNames = new Dictionary<CultureInfo, Dictionary<Languages, string>>
>         {
>             {  // english 
>                 new CultureInfo("en"), new Dictionary<Languages, string>
>                 {
>                     {Languages.English, "English"},
>                     {Languages.French, "French"},
>                     {Languages.German, "German"},
>                     {Languages.Italian, "Italian"},
>                     {Languages.Japanese, "Japanese"},
>                     {Languages.Portuguese, "Portuguese"},
>                     {Languages.Spanish, "Spanish"},
>                 }
>             },
>             {   // french
>                 new CultureInfo("fr"), new Dictionary<Languages, string>
>                 {
>                     {Languages.English, "Anglais"},
>                     {Languages.French, "Français"},
>                     {Languages.German, "Allemand"},
>                     {Languages.Italian, "Italien"},
>                     {Languages.Japanese, "Japonais"},
>                     {Languages.Portuguese, "Portugais"},
>                     {Languages.Spanish, "Espagnol"},
>                 }
>             },
> ```

etc.

Languages enum:

> ```
> public enum Languages
> {
>     English,
>     French,
>     German,
>     Italian,
>     Japanese,
>     Portuguese,
>     Spanish,
> }
> ```

Like I said, it all works perfectly, except, the dropdown list displays the key/value pair, instead of just the language string.. what am I doing wrong?
I'd appreciate any help or suggestions..

Comment: Do you set `ItemTemplate` for the combobox?

Comment: Why did you not just add a "key" property to the `Language` class and use a List collection?

Comment: no itemtemplate, I was considering it.. but I wonder if theirs not already some property that can do this like I thought DisplayMemberPath was supposed to..

Comment: I tried creating a list, and translating for the key, it works, I'll go that way if I have to..

Comment: @John Is it possible that you have some theme enabled? Just to be sure, can you add `ItemTemplate` with binding to `Value`? If there is any `ItemTemplate` set behind, then `DisplayMemberPath` is ignored.

Comment: @ Ulugbek.. no template, set Style="{x:Null}" just to be cautious, but behaves the same.. I'll try to replicate this in a test app..

Comment: @John what it this `Languages` type used as `Key`? Is it another `Dictionary`?

Comment: I have a dictionary 'LanguageNames' with culture keys that contains 7 other dictionaries with the enum/string pair in each language. The LanguageDictionary just returns get { return LanguageNames.CulturedNames[LanguageNames.Culture]; }

Comment: @dzoski Languages is the enum

Comment: @John how do you get `Value` for your `Dictionary` and have you confirmed in debugger that it is what you expect to see?

Comment: @dzoski they appear to be right.. I'm changing it up now though and trying other things

Comment: Post the definition of Languages. Post the code for LanguageManager.LanguageDictionary;

Comment: Not sure why this would cause a display problem but you selected key is bound to a string.  The key need to be bound to the same type as the key - Languages.

Comment: @Blam.. was and has been, made no difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going in another direction entirely..
I put the proper language names in resource dictionaries that also define all the application strings (lang.it.xaml etc), then added them to the combobox as a dynamic resource

```
            <ComboBox Name="LanguageCombo"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding LanguageIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageEnglish}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageFrench}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageGerman}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageItalian}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageJapanese}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguagePortuguese}"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource LanguageSpanish}"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

I then use the index to set the language from a viewmodel property:

VM:

```
    public int LanguageIndex
    {
        get { return _languageIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && _languageIndex != value)
            {
                _languageIndex = value;
                Languages lang = LanguageManager.GetLanguageKey(value);
                LanguageManager.SetLanguage(lang);
                RaisePropertyChanged("LanguageIndex");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ItemsSource works with IEnumerable to display items. A dictionary derives from

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>
```

Try binding to LanguageDictionary.Values instead.

Also, note that neither of these are observable collections, so you won't get updates in your ComboBox. This may be okay depending on your situation, but if you do want updates then take a look at exposing an ObservableCollection for your list of languages.

**UPDATE**:
I just tried using DisplayMemberPath & SelectedValuePath and it worked fine for me...

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:comboBoxTest="clr-namespace:ComboBoxTest"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <comboBoxTest:MyDictionary x:Key="MyDictionary">
        <system:String x:Key="3">Three</system:String>
        <system:String x:Key="4">Four</system:String>
        <system:String x:Key="5">Five</system:String>
    </comboBoxTest:MyDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox"
              DisplayMemberPath="Value"
              SelectedValuePath="Key"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyDictionary}">
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a funny feeling that your types are causing an issue. Key is of type "Languages" and you are binding to a value of type "string" in your SelectedValuePath. Maybe that is what is causing your issue...

Comment: I didn't thumbs you down btw.. but I tried a this, and created a 'translator' to derive the key.. it works, but very hacky. I was thinking datatemplate might be the only solution

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice you were binding to the key. You can also use "DisplayMemberPath" to set the member to use for displaying the same way you're using "SelectedValuePath"

Comment: Actually that's a change, it was the Languages enum, but that stopped working at some point.. maybe I need a objectdataprovider..